# PHP mail() not properly formatted on mobile devices

Tags: php, html-email

I am sending emails with attachments by using PHP mail() function. It is strange but on my computer, I can see properly formatted HTML email with the attached file. When I receive the same email on my Samsung phone it looks like in the picture below
[image: screenshot]

This code:

```
ob_start();
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo     $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<html>
.....html goes here
</html>
```

The code above is getting printed on the mobile devices and the file which is supposed to be attached is being base64 encoded but not attached

this is how my custom mail function looks like:

```
function send_mail_with_attachement($p){
$headers ='';
if(isset($p['from_name'])) $headers .= "From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($p['from_name'])."?= <".$p['from_email'].">\r\n";
if(isset($p['from_email'])) $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($p['from_email']) . "\r\n";
if(!empty($p['cc'])) $headers .= "CC: ". strip_tags($p['cc']) . "\r\n";
if(!empty($p['bcc'])) $headers .= "BCC: ". strip_tags($p['bcc']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["myfiles"]["tmp_name"]))); 
ob_start();
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $p['subject'];?></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="White">
<center>
<div style="font-size:12px;width:620px;padding:5px;margin:0;color:#555;background:#fff;">
<a style="display:block;text-decoration:none;margin:0;padding:0;" href="<?php echo WebSite;?>" target="_blank">
<img style="padding:0;margin:0;border:none;width:100%;" border="0" src="<?php echo WebSite;?>/images/mailheader.jpg" alt="<?php echo official_site_name;?>" />
<div style="background:#cd1718;color:#fff;font-size:11pt;font-weight:700;font-style:italic;margin:0;padding:5px 0;" align="center"><?php echo official_site_name;?></div>
</a>
<div style="padding:5px;text-align:left;font-size:13px;font-family:verdana;"><br><?php echo $p['body'];?><br></div>
<div style="background:#cd1718;color:#fff;margin:0;padding:5px 0;text-align:center;">©Copyright <?php echo date('Y');?>"&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo WebSite;?>" target="_blank" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;"><?php echo official_site_name;?></a> - All Rights Reserved</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>


--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="<?php echo $_FILES['myfiles']['name'];?>"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current     output buffer 
$body = ob_get_clean();


$mail_sent = mail($p['to'], '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode(strip_tags($p['subject'])).'?=', $body, $headers);
return $mail_sent ? true : false;
}
```

What could possibly be the reason of this difference on pc and mobile?

Thank you for any help

Comment: the issue is not in your mobile (I send emails on mobiles/desktop with a custom-made script which builds up the email and attachments, and never encountered such an issue), but on the way the email body is built. Please give us here the smallest sample with the same issue so that we could have a look at the email body (raw content) ; some email readers (such as the one on your desktop) may be more tolerant with bugs in source

Comment: Probably a newline issue. MIME mails need `\r\n` in the headers to work correctly.

Comment: Guys, please check the updated code - I attached my custom mail function